# Extract first and second group (if it exists) from text string in BQ SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, regex-group

My data is in a GCP BQ table.  The following text string is in a column called 'mReports'

```
[{"taskId":"TEST_PLAN","reportId":3751693,"reportType":"TA","timestamp":1689626254539},{"taskId":"REPAIR_SELECTION","reportId":3755434,"reportType":"FRED","timestamp":1689961349740}]
```

I am tring to extract into seperate columns, all occurances of reportType (e.g. TA) and taskID (e.g. TEST_PLAN) from mReports .  Usually there will only be one occurance of each but sometimes there may be upto 3 occurances.  In the example given there are two occurances of each.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(mReports,r'reportType":\W*(\w+)') AS ReportType1,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(mReports,r'taskId":\W*(\w+)') AS TaskId1,
```

Using the above I get:

```
 ReportType1 = TA
 TaskId1 = TEST_PLAN
```

What I would like to get as my output is shown below but I don't know how to get it:

```
ReportType1 = TA
TaskId1 = TEST_PLAN
ReportType2 = FRED
TaskId2 = REPAIR_SELECTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it :

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(json).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
""";

select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_text, '$.taskId') AS taskId,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_text, '$.reportType') AS reportType
from mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(json2array(mytable.mReports) ) as json_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(mReports) FROM (
  SELECT mReports, ReportType, TaskId, OFFSET
  FROM your_table,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(mReports,r'reportType":\W*(\w+)')) AS ReportType WITH OFFSET
  JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(mReports,r'taskId":\W*(\w+)')) AS TaskId WITH OFFSET
  USING(OFFSET)
)
PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(ReportType) as ReportType, ANY_VALUE(TaskId) as TaskId FOR OFFSET + 1 IN (1, 2))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]